# Summary and frequency tables in JMP

Tags: data-visualization, jmp

1. Does anyone know how to create a nice looking summary table in JMP for several variables? I use Tables>Summary and the table I get has one row that includes for example mean(var1) mean(var2) mean(var3) median(var1) median(var2) median(var3) and so on. I would like each variable to have row of its own, with columns representing the statistics.
2. Does anyone know how to create a frequency table when creating a histogram in JMP? I get a histogram by using Analyze>Distributions but I don't see any option of getting the frequency table.

Thank you,

Naama Wolf

Comment: I assume you have found the answers yourself in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

for your first question:

this should be possible with `Table`/ `Create Table`
*(I'm using the german version of `JMP7`, so I'm not sure how the menu commands are called in the english version)*